# Commutative monoidal category free over singleton? Useful in proving coherence?

Tags: category-theory

The proof of coherence in monoidal categories in CWM is based on the
existence of a monoidal category free over a singleton. Denoting this
category by $\mathcal{W}=\left(\mathcal{W}_{0},\square,e_{0},\hat{\alpha},\hat{\lambda},\hat{\rho}\right)$
it can be observed that $\mathcal{W}_{0}$ is a thin groupoid. Its
objects are so-called 'binary words'. For every pair $u,v\in\mathcal{W}_{0}$
the homset $\mathcal{W}_{0}\left(u\square v,v\square u\right)$ contains
exactly one arrow, and denoting it with $\hat{\gamma}_{u,v}$ it seems
to me that $\left(\mathcal{W}_{0},\square,e_{0},\hat{\alpha},\hat{\lambda},\hat{\rho},\hat{\gamma}\right)$
can be recognized as a *commutative* monoidal category. My questions
are:

> 1) Can $\left(\mathcal{W}_{0},\square,e_{0},\hat{\alpha},\hat{\lambda},\hat{\rho},\hat{\gamma}\right)$
>   be classified as a *commutative monoidal category free over a singleton*?
>
> 2) If the answer on the first question is 'yes' then can coherence in
>   *commutative monoidal categories* be proved the same way (used in CWM) as in the proof
>   for monoidal categories?

I think that I am overlooking complications, because the proof in CWM of coherence for monoidal categories appears to be more complex.

Comment: The coherence theorem for monoidal categories is, in some sense, an explicit description of the free monoidal category generated by any category, not just the singleton.

Comment: @ZhenLin If I am not mistaking then the coherence proof for monoidal categories is in essence the theorem stating that 'for any monoidal category $\mathcal B$ and any object $b\in\mathcal B$, there is a unique morphism $\mathcal W\rightarrow \mathcal B$ of monoidal categories with $-\rightarrow b$'. Here '$\{-\}$' is the singleton. In CWM I encountered  monoidal categories free over a set. Not free over a category. My vision is beyond doubt smaller than yours, though.

Comment: Free on a singleton is too small to yield anything useful. Free on a set of objects is better, but in practice what one is really using is free on a category.

Comment: @ZhenLin Implicitly you are saying that the theorem mentioned in my former comment (CWM page 162) is *not* in essence the coherence proof for monoidal categories. Is that correct?

Comment: Having it for the singleton is very far from enough. That would be like concluding that every monoid is commutative, because the free monoid on one generator is...

Comment: @ZhenLin If a category that has exactly one object is monoidal then its composition must indeed be commutative.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. My point is simple: the statement of Theorem 1 in [CWM, Ch. VII, §2] is actually weaker than what is needed in practice; the result we really want is the generalisation of Exercise 3 to free monoidal categories generated by categories. This is how we ensure that all the various natural isomorphisms commute with ordinary morphisms in the expected way.

Comment: @ZhenLin Have a look at this: 'Note that at a first glance, this 'single variable coherence' looks
quite limited .... However, it turns out that the general case follows almost immediately
from this case. The trick is to construct an appropriate monoidal
category $\mathbf{It}\left(\mathcal{B}\right)$ in a way that the
coherence in one variable for $\mathbf{It}\left(\mathcal{B}\right)$
and one special object of $\mathbf{It}\left(\mathcal{B}\right)$ is
the general coherence for $\mathcal{B}$.' http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Mac+Lane\%27s+proof+of+the+coherence+theorem+for+monoidal+categories

Comment: Yes, I know. The point is that you still have to do _something_.